# Can we Store the SSRS Output as Log table .So that to show the difference between yesterday data and today data

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, msbi

Can we Store the Output of the SSRS Report in the Log ?

For Example I have one Sp .In this Sp lot of Sub queries and Xmlpath has been used ,
So we don't have any log in the Db for this Fields which we have called in Sp .

Is it possible to get the Output as I have attached with this Document

I need to know the difference between Yesterday's output and today output .

Please have a look and guide me the way.

Expected Result:
[image: expected result as Image]

The reult should be like in the atatched image

Thanks

Comment: A report can display data from your tables. If you have both yesterday's data and today's data in the database, you dan query the data and compare the records. Until now, this has nothing to do with "reports". What the report can do for you is to highlight the changes.

Comment: NO we dont have yesterday data ad today data to compare the things .can we have any other Comparison by storing the result in temp table and then we can comapre the current result @Wolfgang kais

Comment: If you don't have yesterday's data anymore, then there's nothing you can add to a temp table.

Comment: how i can compare the Current data and with the temp table Data .I have added to temp table .But how I can compare .Row by row data compare

Comment: That depends on the table design, the changes that you expect and how you want to display the changes. Is the ID a unique key that can be used to identify a record? Are `Name` and `Desc` the only fields to compare? Do you need to identify insertions and deletions or just updates? Do you need different background colors for different types of changes?

Comment: Yes Id is unique the only fields are name and Desc .NO need of insertions .Only when the Data is Changed From yesterday Report and today Report .We need to highlight the Certian box.not the Certian Row.for example in one row yesterday in a column it was 12 and now it has chnaged to 13 that time we need to highlight that particular box.

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the data and "calculate" what has changed like this:

```
SELECT n.ID, n.[Name], n.[Desc],
  CASE
    WHEN n.[Name] = o.[Name] THEN 0 
    WHEN n.[Name] IS NULL AND o.[Name] IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END AS NameChanged,
  CASE
    WHEN n.[Desc] = o.[Desc] THEN 0 
    WHEN n.[Desc] IS NULL AND o.[Desc] IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END AS DescChanged
FROM new_data n
  LEFT OUTER JOIN old_data o ON n.ID = o.ID;
```

In the report, use a table to display the data (only columns `ID`, `Name` and `Desc`). Then, for the *BackgroundColor* property (for both textboxes `Name` and `Desc`), use an *Expression*:

- for the `Name` Textbox: `=IIf(Fields!NameChanged.Value = 1, "Gold", Nothing)`
- for the `Desc` Textbox: `=IIf(Fields!DescChanged.Value = 1, "Gold", Nothing)`

You can either use the name of a color that SSRS knows, like `"Gold"`, or specify a color code like `"#FFD800"`.